# matplotlib and pylab plot issues

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I tried to compile matplotlib 1.4.2 and pylab on a centos 7 machine and got tried to run the following program:

```
#!/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl


X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi,256,endpoint=True)
C = np.cos(X)

pl.plot(X,C)
```

When I ran this program I got the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 11, in <module>
    pl.plot(X,C)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-    x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3092, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-    x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 828, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-  x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 462, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 435, in figure
**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-  x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 47, in      new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 54, in   new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-   x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 72, in __init__
    FigureCanvasQT.__init__(self, figure)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py", line 68, in __init__
_create_qApp()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 138, in _create_qApp
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

Do know you what could be causing these errors?  How can I produce plots with matplot lib 1.4.2?  I did echo the variable $DISPLAY and nothing appears.  How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may want to check `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: What about the other error messages?  When I checked echo $DISPLAY nothing appeared.